# How to find nth Fibonacci number using Javascript with O(n) complexity

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, time-complexity, fibonacci

Trying really hard to figure out how to solve this problem. The problem being finding nth number of Fibonacci with O(n) complexity using javascript.

I found a lot of great articles how to solve this using C++ or Python, but every time I try to implement the same logic I end up in a `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Example code in Python

```
MAX = 1000

# Create an array for memoization
f = [0] * MAX

# Returns n'th fuibonacci number using table f[]
def fib(n) :
        # Base cases
        if (n == 0) :
                return 0
        if (n == 1 or n == 2) :
                f[n] = 1
                return (f[n])

        # If fib(n) is already computed
        if (f[n]) :
                return f[n]

        if( n & 1) :
                k = (n + 1) // 2
        else : 
                k = n // 2

        # Applyting above formula [Note value n&1 is 1
        # if n is odd, else 0.
        if((n & 1) ) :
                f[n] = (fib(k) * fib(k) + fib(k-1) * fib(k-1))
        else :
                f[n] = (2*fib(k-1) + fib(k))*fib(k)

        return f[n]


// # Driver code
// n = 9
// print(fib(n))
```

Then trying to port this to Javascript

```
const MAX = 1000;
let f = Array(MAX).fill(0);
let k;

const fib = (n) => {

    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
        f[n] = 1;

        return f[n]
    }

    if (f[n]) {
        return f[n]
    }

    if (n & 1) {
        k = Math.floor(((n + 1) / 2))
    } else {
        k = Math.floor(n / 2)
    }

    if ((n & 1)) {
        f[n] = (fib(k) * fib(k) + fib(k-1) * fib(k-1))
    } else {
        f[n] = (2*fib(k-1) + fib(k))*fib(k)
    }

    return f[n]
}

console.log(fib(9))
```

That obviously doesn't work. In Javascript this ends up in an infinite loops. So how would you solve this using Javascript?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using tail recursion or dynamic programming.

Comment: The same way you would do it by hand. Calculate the next number from the prvious two. No recursion needed. No storing of more than the prvious 2 values needed.

Comment: @OmG thanks, solved it

Comment: `In Javascript this ends up in an infinite loops` ...

Comment: @iremlopsum Do you know that you can post answer to your own question?

Comment: @iremlopsum: Your question isn't asking for the bug in your code, but your comment below suggests that's what you actually wanted. If you didn't want different solutions, why ask for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to scope of the `k` variable. It must be inside of the function:

```
const fib = (n) => {
    let k;
```

You can find far more good implementations here [list](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Fibonacci_Number_Program)

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/72dgy23c/)

Comment: This the correct answer, thanks, I solved it in a different way initially that works. But you pointed out the correct problem with my code :)

Comment: I have edited my answer to add a link, that can be helpfull

Answer (score 3):

you can iterate from bottom to top (like tail recursion):

```js
var fib_tail = function(n){
        if(n == 0)
             return 0;
        if(n == 1 || n == 2)
             return 1;
        var prev_1 = 1, prev_2 = 1, current; 
        // O(n)
        for(var i = 3; i <= n; i++)
        {
            current = prev_1 + prev_2;
            prev_1 = prev_2;
            prev_2 = current;
        }
        return current;
 }
 console.log(fib_tail(1000))
```

Comment: @rockstar I mean iterating from bottom to top. Anyhow, removed it.

Answer (score 1):

fibonacci number in O(n) time and O(1) space complexity:

```
function fib(n) {
    let prev = 0, next =1;
    if(n < 0)
        throw 'not a valid value';
    if(n === prev || n === next)
        return n;
    while(n >= 2) {
        [prev, next] = [next, prev+next];
        n--;
    }
    return next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use two variables and a loop that counts down the number provided.

```js
function fib(n){
    let [a, b] = [0, 1];
    while (--n > 0) {
      [a, b] = [b, a+b];
    }
    return b;
}

console.log(fib(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler way to go about it, using either iterative or recursive methods:

```
function FibSmartRecursive(n, a = 0, b = 1) {
    return n > 1 ? FibSmartRecursive(n-1, b, a+b) : a;
}

function FibIterative(n) {
    if (n < 2) 
        return n;

    var a = 0, b = 1, c = 1;

    while (--n > 1) {
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = a + b;
    }

    return c;
}

function FibMemoization(n, seenIt = {}) {//could use [] as well here
    if (n < 2) 
        return n;
    if (seenIt[n]) 
        return seenIt[n];

    return seenIt[n] = FibMemoization(n-1, seenIt) + FibMemoization(n-2, seenIt); 
}

console.log(FibMemoization(25)); //75025
console.log(FibIterative(25)); //75025
console.log(FibSmartRecursive(25)); //75025
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem without recursion using loops, runtime O(n):

```
function nthFibo(n) {
    // Return the n-th number in the Fibonacci Sequence
    const fibSeq = [0, 1]
    if (n < 3) return seq[n - 1]
    let i = 1
    while (i < n - 1) {
        seq.push(seq[i - 1] + seq[i])
        i += 1
    }
    return seq.slice(-1)[0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Using Recursion
const fib = (n) => {
  if (n <= 2) return 1;
  return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}

console.log(fib(4)) // 3
console.log(fib(10)) // 55
console.log(fib(28)) // 317811
console.log(fib(35)) // 9227465
```